# Set background for disabled listview items

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I'm writing a program which uses a Listview (with a custom adapter) and I want to disable some items in the listview. I'm doing so by using this code (so far so good):

```
@Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
        if ((position == 2 || position == 3) && mBool1) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

However, this doesn't provide any visual cues... only the fact that after you set the boolean mBool1, you can't click on list items at positions 2 and 3, but the background stays the same. How can I change the background color for disabled listview items to be different from the enabled ones? I'm trying to use a selector, but I can't find the right combination.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

And it shouldn't. All the visual state is calculated in `getView` (or `bindView`, depends on adapter type you are using). So you should do something like:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Get the view
    if(isEnabled(position)) {
        view.setBackground(...);
    } else {
        view.setBackground(...);
    }
}
```